# Error: Open (GetCommState) : Unknown error code 1 - Nodejs, express, SerialPort

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-serialport

I am trying to connect a fiscal printer that has serial input to nodejs. I'm using the SerialPort module, but I can't make the connection, since the console gives me the following error: "Error: Open (GetCommState): Unknow error code 1". I would like to know if you could help me with this error, or tell me where I can find the meaning of each of the errors, since I do not know what the error code 1 means

```
  const SerialPort = require("serialport")
  const Readline = SerialPort.parsers.Readline
  const parser = new Readline
  const mySerial = new SerialPort('COM2', {
     baudRate: 9600
   })
   mySerial.on('open', () => {
     console.log("Port COM2")
   })
```

The error:

[ERROR: OPEN (GETCOMMSTATE: UNKNOWN ERROR CODE 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7y0fW.png)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there is no printer installed in Windows on the same port. Had the same problem, I just uninstalled the printer and it solved.